# How is Spree.config implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm studying Spree's source code and I came across the snippet.

```
Spree.config do |config|
  # Example:
  # Uncomment to override the default site name.
  # config.site_name = "Spree Demo Site"
end
```

How is this being implemented? I cannot find Spree.config defined anywhere as a method. I'm guessing some meta-programming is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is defined in https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core.rb (line 68 at this time).

`config` is a module method on the `Spree` module. It's implementation passes the `Spree::Config` object to the given block.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Does this mean that `Spree::Config` is just an arbitrary object? When I type `Spree::Config` into the console, it returns `#<Spree::AppConfiguration:0x007f7f45d0ed98>`. I don't see code that 'connects` `Spree::Config` and `Spree::AppConfiguration`.

Comment: Seems as though `Config` is just a constant again in the `Spree` that gets set in https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/engine.rb (line 41) as part of the initialisation of the Rails engine. The `AppConfiguration` object is created in https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/environment.rb